# Single real value from Random Value node

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I make the following possible?
Goal is to add a point when a certain condition is met.
The problem is that Random Value produces a field and not a single value.
Shouldn't it make sense that the output of a `Random Value` would be a Diamond with Dot?

[image]

Comment: The output of the _Random Value_ is diamond-shaped because it is capable of outputting fields. A dot inside would indicate that at the moment the output only provides a single value. Since by default it is using all indices of the geometry if nothing else is plugged in the _ID_ socket, there is a field of random values at the output so no, it would not make any sense if it showed a diamond with a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID input by default uses the ID field (BTW, the ID field usually is populated with indices, but it doesn't matter, if you set all IDs to 0, it's still a field). So connect to the ID a constant (e.g. an "Integer" node), and you will get a constant output as well.

[image]

Example taken from another answer of mine:

[Geonodes: Adding 'Random Value' to 'Noise Texture' (4D/W) yields strange results](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299170/60486)